# Developing multiple page application with emberjs?

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I want develop a multi page web application with emberjs.

For Eg: 
1)Login page
2) Mian view

First login page is shown, once login successfull, I need to show main view, which contains other sub views(like navigation).

I think for this, emberJS, statemanger and router are imporatant. But guys there is very very less document for the basics on this.

Could you please guide me, how to proceed!.

Thanks all

Answer (score 6):

This is the collection that I have, pick as per your understanding level in Ember

**From Ember Official**

[Docs](http://emberjs.com/documentation/)

[Guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/)

[API](http://emberjs.com/api/)

[More Advanced & In Detail Docs from Emberjs github project](https://github.com/emberjs/website/tree/master/source/guides) (This will be on the official site in the future I guess)

[Ember Data](https://github.com/emberjs/data)

**Some key concepts**

[Understanding Ember Object](http://www.cerebris.com/blog/2012/03/06/understanding-ember-object/)

[Naming Conventions](http://www.emberist.com/2012/04/09/naming-conventions.html)

[Absolute Paths in Classes](http://www.emberist.com/2012/04/30/absolute-paths-in-classes.html)

**Examples**

[Ember Todo](https://github.com/emberjs/todos)

[Smallest Viable Ember Application](http://trek.github.com/)

Extras

[Useful Ember Functions](http://code418.com/blog/2012/03/08/useful-emberjs-functions/)

[Ember Links](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/wiki/Links)